# Covariant derivative of inner product

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors, riemannian-geometry

I'm reading the Wikipedia page on Levi-Civita connections, and there's a step that I don't quite follow in one of the derivations. I was wondering if someone could help.

Suppose $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are vector fields on a manifold $M$, $\nabla$ is an affine connection on $M$ and $g$ is a Riemannian metric on $M$.

How can one show that $X (g(Y, Z)) = g(\nabla_X Y, Z) + g(Y, \nabla_X Z)$ using only the definition of $\nabla$? Do we require compatibility with the metric?

Edit: one of the comments has pointed out that this is the definition of compatibility with the metric. I don't see how to derive this relationship from the definition that I've seen, i.e. $\nabla g = 0$. Thanks!

Edit 2: Question is now a dupe of [Equivalent definition of metric compatibility for a connection: what does $\nabla g$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749725/equivalent-definition-of-metric-compatibility-for-a-connection-what-does-nabl)

Comment: Could you please double-check the equality you mention? It doesn't make sense as it is, since $g$ takes two inputs and the RHS only has one. If the equality you want is $Xg(Y,Z)=g(\nabla_XY,Z)+g(Y,\nabla_X Z)$, then it is usually the *definition* of compatibility with the metric (if it is not the definition, please put the definition you are using).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to write $X(g(Y, Z)) = g(\nabla_X Y, Z) + g(Y, \nabla_X Z)$

Comment: This equation is definitely a main part of the Riemannian connection definition.